# Writing Json to existing file .json without "syntax errors"

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

This one may be a tad tricky to understand if I'm not clear. I want to open a `.json` file, which contains an `array` and add/`append` to that `array` but I keep coming into format problems with the `array`. I first thought this needed to be PHP but I don't see why it couldn't be JS now.

Some may ask, why aren't I using a database, it just won't work for what I want to do. I just what to store data in a file on-site without a database.

**analytics.php** on execution adds the data to the data.json file. The plan is to call this on every visit (small site).

```
$visitArray = [];

$visitArray["ip"] = "127.0.0.1";
$visitArray["referrer"] = "www.google.com";
$visitArray["conversion"] = "nil";
$visitArray["bounce"] = "nil";
$visitArray["platform"] = "Chrome";
$VisiterArray[] = $visitArray;



$data = json_encode($VisiterArray);
$data = $data;
file_put_contents("data.json", $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

**data.json** (when **analytics.php** is executed)

```
[
   {
    "ip":"127.0.0.1",
    "referrer":"www.google.com",
    "conversion":"nil",
    "bounce":"nil",
    "platform":"Chrome"
   }
]
```

The problem is if you run the **analytics.php** there's no "," and I don't think it's as easy to solve to change `$data = $data;` to `$data = $data.',';` it just seems like a terrible way to do things.

```
    [
   {
    "ip":"127.0.0.1",
    "referrer":"www.google.com",
    "conversion":"nil",
    "bounce":"nil",
    "platform":"Chrome"
   }
]
    // missing ","
[
   {
    "ip":"127.0.0.1",
    "referrer":"www.google.com",
    "conversion":"nil",
    "bounce":"nil",
    "platform":"Chrome"
   }
]
```

Comment: Bad idea in so many ways

Comment: Thought it might be and the alt?

Comment: Why not just use a CSV with 5 values?

Comment: @apokryfos oh God...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do isn't easily achievable, as just adding a ',' would also result in invalid json (as your arrays would also need to be in an array)

Easiest solution would be just unserialise your JS and append it there. Something like

```
$VisiterArray = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"));
$visitArray = [];

$visitArray["ip"] = "127.0.0.1";
$visitArray["referrer"] = "www.google.com";
$visitArray["conversion"] = "nil";
$visitArray["bounce"] = "nil";
$visitArray["platform"] = "Chrome";
$VisiterArray[] = $visitArray;

$data = json_encode($VisiterArray);
file_put_contents("data.json", $data);
```

Although this isn't really ideal for logging.

If you really did want to do it that way, you could probably kinda cheat. Ie. append a "," after each entery like you suggested, then read it with something like `$data = json_decode("[".file_get_contenst("data.json")."]");` which may work - although the file isn't really json at this point, so its a little hacky/nasty IMO. As others have suggested, a standard log file format probably makes more sense.

Comment: The problem is this becomes slow very quickly. Still, the OP did say "small site."

Comment: Indeed, my suggestion is a pretty terrible idea for a logger :p Like you said, common log format makes a lot more sense

Comment: This crossed my mind but double handling it, is a tad too much. I think I'm starting to see the light with this approach, as in to move away from it completely. Is there a better way to store data to a similar effect without the downfalls and complexities ?

Comment: Assuming you have a standard set of columns, comma separated values are easy to work with + you can freely just append em to the end of your log.

Comment: and write to a txt file or something? thanks for your help I'll look into "common log format" as it means nothing to me, yet!

Comment: Its kinda up to you, if your using comma separated values, `.csv` probably makes most sense for a file extension (Also means excel or similar will open it by default), but its all really text at the end of the day :)

Comment: Thanks Carl, you have been a big help, people like you make this site great! could feel I was taking a wrong turn! Thanks again!

Comment: @Benjamin And what happens if comeone actually visits your site! Or maybe 1000's of people. You file will get BIG very QUICK so your `$VisiterArray = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"));` will take longer and longer. Imagine it has 200,000 visits logged in it, **or maybe 200,000,000**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have decided to write to a .csv file? this should help, right? no decode needed and I only need to process the file when I want to look at my stats. Still not ideal but I'm really not seeing any other way (without a database)

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't *just* a missing `,`, even if you had a `,` there, it would be an invalid JSON file.

The problem you have is that both of the "container" types JSON has (array and object) require a termination character. Adding to the means inserting *in front of* that termination character — in your case, in front of that trailing `]` so you can just add another object to the base array.

This makes JSON a less-than-ideal format for log files. Suggest using any of the standard HTTP log file formats, such as the [common log format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format), and then converting to JSON as necessary after-the-fact.